# How to manipulate strings in a Blogger template. Impossible?

Tags: title, blogger, blogspot, strip-tags

> **This question is about Blogger Template manipulation**. People developing/changing or manipulating Blogger templates in any way know its syntax hence can provide some input.

I write a [development blog](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com) on Blogger and I've changed my blog template so posts display HTML `head` title differently (post name first) from default (blog name first).

But. Since I format my inline programming code words similarly to Stackoverflow (gray background mono-spaced font) and do the same when I use any of them in blog post title... I enclose such code words inside `<code/>` element and then I have CSS set for this particular element to add it gray background and set mono-spaced font on it. This formatting works on blog post titles and its content.

But the problem I'm having is that these `<code/>` tags I use are also displayed in the HTML `head` `title` (displayed in browser window title). What is even more importan is that these get displayed in [web search results](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aerraticdev.blogspot.com) as well. That's even more annoying.

Default template uses `<data:blog.pageTitle/>` in `title` element, which strips out any tags, but displays all titles as *Blog Name: Blog post title* (Google search results are quite meaningless because blog post title gets cut off). That's why I'm using `<data:blog.pageName/>` instead to display just blog post title in the head, but it still has all tags and I should strip them out somehow.

Check [this blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-correctly-use-ihttpmodule-to.html) example. Load it, and look at browser's window title bar that still has tags displayed. I want them gone.

**How do I strip tags from the post title when adding it to `head` element?**

Comment: hi Robert, i have updated my responce in order to have a more usefull answer. let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**

ok, so far this is what i worked out:

1. under settings -> Title -> put a nice `&nbsp;`
2. use `<data:blog.pageTitle/>` as title;
3. under design -> edit html -> replace theese lines

---

```
<b:section class='header' id='header' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
  <b:widget id='Header1' locked='true' title='  (Intestazione)' type='Header'/>
</b:section>
```

with your custom header like

```
<div class="header section" id="header">
  <div class="widget Header" id="Header1">
    <div id="header-inner">
      <div class="titlewrapper">
        <h1 class="title">
          <a href="http://aseptik.blogspot.com/">aSeptik Site</a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="descriptionwrapper">
        <p class="description">
          <span>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`<title>` will result from:

```
jQuery <em>"scroll into view"</em> plugin (with an additional <code>":scrollable"</code> selector filter)
```

to

```
: jQuery "scroll into view" plugin (with an additional ":scrollable" selector filter)
```

hope this help, **demo** http://aseptik.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html

---

try with a little bit of javascript in your `<body>` like this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.title = document.title.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,&#39;&#39;);
</script>

</body>
```

copy and past as is don't convert entities,

> - **DEMO:** http://aseptik.blogspot.com/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html
>
> although, i'm not sure this is the
>   right solution for you since spiders
>   usually avoid js execution, and i
>   don't know how "*html tags in the title*"
>   affects the search results.

Comment: You're right. The problem is not just window title but more importantly web crawlers. I'll put this in the question because it is just as important as everything else. BUT it got me thinking of another possible solution. I could hide original post title element and add my custom title in content. Tedious when changing post title, but that doesn't happen as often as one may think. I suppose.

Comment: you can always use <data:blog.pageTitle/> and leave the site-name empty and use your custom <h1>my site</h1>. this should be a more reliable solution i guess. this way your title will result in something like : jquery blah blah

Comment: @aSeptik: Unfortunatelly I don't have any setting called **site name** under blog settings. I do have **Title** though but when I change it to no-breaking-space I loose my blog title that's displayed at the top of my blog.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: sorry, my bad, i mean **Title**, SO was not showing the full code i have provided, i have updated it once again. ;) Yes, the trik is hide the default Title and replace it with custom one. look at the snippet.

Comment: Thanks @aSeptik. This should do the trick actually. It makes blog title static though, but how often does one change blog title? :) The only problem staying there is the colon at the beginning (window title) because blog title equals space. For the time being I removed all tags from titles, but I'm about to change my blog template and I'll do something about it after I change the template. Unfortunately bounty has expired in the meantime, so I only accepted your answer and awarded you additional up vote which adds up to 25 points. Sorry about that.

Comment: don't warry about points, you are welcome. it's just a pleasure. ;)